# appendTo pushes window and scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm using appendTo to add a set of selected elements to a certain DOM element:

```
$('#incoming-items').appendTo($('#item-list'));
```

(#incoming products is a place holder for items received by an Ajax call. My expectation is that:

1. the elements will be added after #item-list
2. the viewport, the window will be kept at the position it previously was. For example, if item-list fits inside the window like

---

item1

item2

item3

---

incoming items item7, item8 should (and usually) keep it like this and are added below the viewport:

---

item1

item2

item3

---

item7

item8

**BUT: what happens sometimes (especially when the scroll bar is at the bottom) is that item7 and 8 are shown instead (and item1, 2 are pushed up):**

---

item3

item7

item8

---

Now this happens only in Firefox!

any ideas? something?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var scroll = $('#incoming_items').scrollTop();    
$('#incoming-items').appendTo($('#item-list'));
$('#incoming_items').scrollTop(scroll);
```

which will store the current scroll position (in pixels from the top) and jump back to it, no matter what happens to the underlying div.

Comment: you're the man. the approach works! I had to change the selector on which you apply scrollTop to be the whole html tag, so that the it would be the browser's scroll bar (scrollTop of a specific item pertains to an internal scroll bar. So now it looks like :

     var scroll = $("html").scrollTop();

     $('#incoming-items').appendTo($('#item-list'));

     $('html').scrollTop(scroll);

and it works!

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought you had a fixed-height div with an internal scroll bar. That works :) Glad to be of help!